# JavaFX ComboBox Special Characters

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, fxml

If I create a Combobox, doesn't matter if I use FXML or Java code, the default value is displayed wrong:

[image: Error Picture]

I use for both (items and setValue()) the same letters: "Männlich"
Even if I don't set a default value but let it take the first one it doesn't work.
Why is the special char not recognized for the default value in the first place?

After selecting manually the value again it is displayed correctly.

Example:

```
ComboBox genderField = new ComboBox();
genderField.getItems().addAll("Männlich", "Weiblich");
```

File encoding is UTF-8.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: elaborate i do not get you

Answer (score 1):

I tried to recreate your issue without success.

A potential quick fix is to swap out all your special characters with their unicode equivalents.

So for ä you'll use \u00E4 instead.

Example:

```
ComboBox genderField = new ComboBox();
genderField.getItems().addAll("M\u00E4nnlich", "Weiblich");
```

You can find all the Unicode character codes at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters